# IsEnabled property cannot be binded to a DependencyProperty and IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have the following code:

**XAML code:**

```
<Window x:Class="combobinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:combobinding"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:EnumConverter x:Key="isEnabledConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="Hello"  IsEnabled="{Binding SectionTitle, Converter={StaticResource isEnabledConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C# Code**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SectionTitleProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SectionTitle),
                         typeof(SectionTitle),
                         typeof(MainWindow));

        public SectionTitle SectionTitle
        {
            get { return (SectionTitle)GetValue(SectionTitleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SectionTitleProperty, value); }
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SectionTitle = SectionTitle.TitleBlock;
        }
    }

    public enum SectionTitle
    {
        Normal,
        TitleBlock
    }
    public class EnumConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var sectionType = (SectionTitle)value;
            if (sectionType == SectionTitle.Normal)
                return true;
            return false;

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

I would expect that the `EnumConverter` would be called as I am setting the `DependencyProperty` `SectionTitle` and any breakpoint inside the method will be hit.

However this doesn't seem to be the case; and the `IsEnabled` property is not being binded to `SectionTitle` as I wish.

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `DataContext`. The binding does not find its target.

You can set the context in the declaration of the window. Add this to the `Window` tag in your XAML:

```
 DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Define `Name` property on your `Window` with `Name="MyWindow"`, then use it in your binding like this:

```
<TextBox Text="Hello" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=SectionTitle, Converter={StaticResource isEnabledConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the DataContext of your MainWindow. You can esaily do this inside the constructor:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    ...
```

Comment: I thought `DependencyProperty` already handles `INotifyPropertyChanged`?